# Docker ASP.net core making https call to identity provider fails due to SSL

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ssl

I have two containers. The first contains an openId connect microservice that serves as Identity provider. The secon contains an API.
Both containers build well and requests work well when made from the host machine.
But when the API controller calls the Identity controller to authenticate requests, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://company.identityprovider.staging/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42  ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://company.identityprovider.staging/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42  ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42  ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2023-01-19 22:52:42    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

What I did:
I created self signed certificates as recommended by the Microsoft documentation online, my containers could now be accessed via https, but couldn't still talk to each other because of the error above.

I then went online and searched how to create a CA (certificate authority) and create my own certificates. Then generated a .pfx file from this certificate, then installed the same certificate authority in both docker containers and made ASP.net core use the certificate for ssl, but this still didn't work.

When I run curl in the container, I get this error:

> curl: (60) SSL: certificate subject name 'certificateName' does not match target host name
> 'containername'
> More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
> establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
> how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Please, how can I make these Apis communicate via SSL ?

I've tried so many solutions, but none works.

Comment: What is the Common Name (CN) of the CA certificate and what are the domain names used to communicate between the 2 containers?

Comment: I called the CA "localhost" and I use the docker service name to communicate between them. for example, my container with the IDP, I call it with the url: 'https://company.identityprovider.staging:443' where company.identityprovider.staging is the service name in the docker compose file

Comment: Then I guess that's where the issue is comming from; the CA doesn't match the domain name? I'm wondering, is SSL communication between containers necessary? If you use a reverse proxy to direct traffic from the client to the docker containers then I think SSL should only be used between the reverse proxy and the client?

Comment: The communication between containers in ssl is neccessary, since the openId connect identity provider API validates tokens from other APIs and it requires calls to be done over SSL. I set the CA to be localhost because I configured it on localhost, but it didn't change anything